# Generic term for sunrise and sunset

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a single generic term to refer, either collectively or arbitrarily, to both *sunrises* and *sunsets*?

I'm looking for something that could be used in the same vein as *twilight* can be used (formally or informally) to refer to both the pre-sunrise *dawn* period and the post-sunset *dusk* period, without specifying which.

I'm aware of the concept of a [*golden hour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hour_%28photography%29) within the photography and cinematography communities, but I'm looking for something which refers more to the specific astronomical event, as a particular instant in time, while still being agnostic to the direction the sun is going.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'd like something that could describe, even informally, any or all of:

1. Instants when the sun is exactly at the horizon, or 0°,
2. Periods when the sun is near the horizon on either side, e.g., –2° to +2°, or
3. Periods when the sun is near the horizon, but strictly above it, e.g., 0° to +2°.

I am aware of the [various astronomical definitions of *twilight*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight#Definitions), but unfortunately none of them meets any of these.

Comment: There's a beautiful Sanskrit word that describes what you are looking for. It is called "sandhya".

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for either, but "green flash" or "green ray" refers to an optical phenomenon that occurs for an instant before or after sunrise or sunset. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_flash. Eric Roemer made this phenomenon the symbolic center of _Le Rayon Vert_ (aka _Summer_), a film he directed in 1986—recommended if you like Roemer's other films.

Comment: *Twilight* as technically defined, is exactly what you are asking for. If is not what you want, you need to explain why not.

Comment: For my own [question closed as a duplicate of yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536631/name-for-the-group-comprised-of-sunrise-and-sunset) I was looking for sunrise and 120 minutes after where computer monitor brightens. Also sunset and 90 minutes before where computer monitor dims. Which is opposite of your definition. Anyway a comment suggested "Transitional Daylight Periods". But I would use "Transitional Light Times" instead. At the end I'm going with "Sun Times" to categorize Sunrise and Sunset. Twilight sounds like a cheesy teenager romance novel of the supernatural.

Comment: I'm interested in a word for this too. Twilight is technically incorrect because if the sun is above the horizon it's not Twilight.

Answer (score 7):

The word *[twilight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twilight)* actually means what you're looking for:

> **twilight**, *n*.: the light from the sky between full night and sunrise *or* between sunset and full night

Animals that are active during twilight are said to be *[crepuscular](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-do-the-terms-crepuscular-diurnal-and-nocturnal-mean.htm)*, so if you're looking for an adjective to apply to that period, *crepuscular* (which is itself derived from the Latin for *twilight*) should serve.

Edit: Lacking the context in which you wish to use the term you're looking for, I can offer these suggestions:

Sunset/sunrise occur at the instant that the sun's upper limb is tangent to the horizon. You could then, for example, have science officer of some enterprising starship reporting, "Two degrees to ***limb tangency***, Captain" to mark some impending sunrise/sunset/moonrise/moonset/et ceteraset.

Sunset/sunrise occur at a precise *zenith distance* of 90.8333 degrees. You could coin a term for this value, so that the same science officer could report, "Two arc seconds from ***zenith distance alpha***, Captain."

Comment: Please re-read my question; I want to describe specific events at specific instants in time, not the periods of time surrounding those instants nor the light from them.

Comment: I think he’s looking for the time when the sun is in sky, not below the horizon like with *twilight*.  So he wants something for the time right after dawn and the time right before dusk. So when a star is near the horizon, but above it.

Comment: @tchrist Right. We use _sunrise_ to refer to the precise time at which the sun comes up from the horizon, as well as more informally to the period of time approximating that instant. That's the kind of thing I'm going for.

Comment: Both sunrise and sunset occur at the precise instant that the sun's upper limb is tangent to the horizon (usually an idealized one). I haven't been able to to find a general term for that instant of tangency.

Comment: @Gnawme It's quite possibly a lacuna. Or perhaps just a very technical term. I don't know... but I guess that's why I'm asking!

Comment: [By definition](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/RST_defs.php), sunrise and sunset occur at a _zenith distance_ of 90.8333 degrees (90 degrees, 50 minutes). Possibly an organization whose bread and butter involved zenith distance would have its own jargon for specific instances of zenith distance (which on its own has an interesting ring...).

Answer (score 3):

[**Nautical twilight**](http://digital-photography-school.com/beyond-sunset-the-differen-phases-of-twilight) occurs right after civil twilight in the evening, and right before civil twilight in the morning. This phase occurs **when the center of the sun is between 6 and 12 degrees below the horizon in the morning and evening.** This period also usually lasts around 30 minutes and the primary color cast across the atmosphere is usually a deep blue tone with still noticeable orange and yellow hues left over from the fading sun. The horizon is still visible during this time... The light has started to dissipate quickly and silhouettes are going to be more prevelent... Details will be harder to make out during this time but there is still some remaining light on the horizon from the sun.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [crepuscular](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crepuscular)... see if that fits your needs.

> Definition of crepuscular in English:
>   adjective
>   
>   1. Resembling or relating to twilight.
>
> 1.1. Zoology (Of an animal) appearing or active in twilight.

Source:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crepuscular

Comment: Consider adding a definition of crepuscular to your answer -- it'll make it easier to evaluate whether it fits the OPs need.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [***twilight zone***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORbseYAkzRM), or the ***terminator***:

> A **terminator** or **twilight zone** is a moving line that divides the daylit side and the dark night side of a planetary body. A terminator is defined as the locus of points on a planet or moon where the line through its parent star is tangent. An observer on the terminator of such an orbiting body with an atmosphere would experience twilight due to light scattering by particles in the gaseous layer.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(solar))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Horizon crossing, or solar horizon crossing? That doesn't account for non-flat terrain though.