# Name for the group comprised of Sunrise and Sunset

Tags: single-word-requests

This is not a duplicate of:

- [Generic term for sunrise and sunset](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144639/generic-term-for-sunrise-and-sunset)

I'm looking for the word which indentifies the group of "Sunrise" and "Sunset". For example "Volvo" and "Ford" could be members of groups called "cars" or "vehicles".

Instinctively I would call the group "Sun times" but I wonder if there is an official word?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single word for sunrise, sunset, twilight etc.

However, you could say that they are *transitions* or *stages of sunlight/daylight*.

Sunrise, sunset, twilight (dawn, dusk, noon etc) are *stages of sunlight*.

Answer (score 0):

OED:

> **twilight, n**.
>
> **1. The light diffused by the reflection of the sun's rays from the atmosphere before sunrise, and after sunset; the period during which this prevails between daylight and darkness.**
>
> 1796   J. Morse American Universal Geography (new ed.) I. 52   *The twilight is that faint light which opens the morning by little and little in the east, before the sun rises; and gradually shuts in the evening in the west, after the sun is set.*

Comment: There used to be a comment under the question suggesting **Transitional Daylight Times** which I would have accepted as an answer if it was **Transitional Sun Times** but strangely all the comments under the question have disappeared.